# Python 3 - Finding single number within a non-empty array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to solve a leetcode problem, in which I have to find the number in a list that does not repeat. I have written this code, but it fails in this test case. I cannot seem to understand why it fails in this case. Can someone give me an explanation?

this is the code:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:

        i = 0
        while True:

            if nums.count(nums[i]) == 1:
                return nums[i]
                break
            else:
                nums.remove(nums[i])
                i = i + 1
```

After passing 28 test cases it fails the case where nums = [1, 0, 1]

I have found another solution, so I am most interested in an explanation of why this code fails the given test case. Because I honestly don't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to return the number itself, not it's index

Comment: do all numbers repeat twice except single number ?

Comment: You remove an element from the array and then increment `i`. This causes you to skip an element. Try to track this on a piece of paper

Comment: you can use single line if each number is repeating except one then index will be `nums.index(reduce(lambda x,y: x^y, nums))`

Comment: your code failed because you are calculating the count(1) in the list which is not equal to 1 so you removed that element, so both 1 will be removed now you are left with [0] which is at index 0 and your loop is over but you didn't get the result.

Comment: lambda approach incorrect for `[1, 0, 1, 1]
`

Comment: @user19077881 this approach is for finding out the element that is not duplicated. So assuming that numbers are repeating twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that this code passed 28 test cases without triggering the bug. The way that you use `remove` is buggy, and also not needed. I don't see any good reason to mutate the list.

The core problem is that you seem to think that `remove` removes all occurrences on an item. It doesn't -- it only removes the first occurrence.

With the test case that it fails, `[1,0,1]` you start with `i = 0`, hence you look at the first `1`. Its count is > 1, so you call the remove method with it. The resulting list is `[0,1]`. At this point`i` is incremented to `1`, which is the index of `1` in the list. Since the first `1` has been removed, the count of the remaining `1` is 1. Your code thus returns `1` as the answer, rather than the correct answer of `0`.

As a general rule of thumb, it is a bad idea to mutate a list while iterating over it. The way that indices of items can shift because of the list mutation is a frequent source of bugs.